# Stop (most) local delivery in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, aliases

I'm trying to setup a Postfix (2.11.4) configuration so that it does this:

1. Sends out mail originating from the local server
2. Accepts incoming mail for a single alias, which actually points to a script
3. And nothing else

Here's a partial main.cf:

```
mydomain               = example.com
inet_interfaces        = all
inet_protocols         = all
mydestination          = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
alias_maps             = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database         = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
relayhost              = outbound.example.com
allow_mail_to_commands = alias,forward,include
allow_mail_to_files    = alias,forward,include
luser_relay            = $local@example.com
```

For #1, mail generated on the server for someone@example.com automatically gets sent to "outbound.example.com" for processing.  And for #2, I have this in /etc/postfix/aliases , so messages to "robot@myserver.example.com" can be processed by a Perl script

```
robot: | "/usr/local/bin/robomail.pl"
```

So far so good.  It's #3 that is giving me trouble.

See, this server used to run Sendmail with domain masquerading turned on.  And there are still some apps on this server (which I **do not** control) that send e-mail to just "george" (for example) and expect the server to convert that automatically to "george@example.com", which then gets routed to "outbound.example.com" for delivery.

I tried to fix this by setting up a `luser_relay` directive:

```
luser_relay = $local@example.com
```

This sort of works - when local delivery to "george" fails, Postfix will rewrite it to george@example.com

But if "george" is actually a valid account on the server (i.e. listed in /etc/passwd), then Postfix will accept the message and deliver it to a local mail directory, instead of rewriting the address and forwarding it.

I can work around this by making another /etc/postfix/aliases entry:

```
george: george@example.com
```

But this is obviously not scalable when the server has dozens of local user accounts, with more being added all the time.  And as best I can tell from the documentation, there's no wildcard equivalent for /etc/postfix/aliases.  Otherwise, I would want to do something like this:

```
robot: | "/usr/local/bin/robomail.pl"
*: *@example.com
```

Is there a way in Postfix to do this?  Accept mail for "robot", but forward everything else to "outbound.example.com" for delivery (adding the @example.com if necessary)?

**UPDATE:**
Some postconf details, and the log of a message that gets sent from "root" to "george" on the local server:

```
myhostname = myserver.example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
masquerade_domains = 

Mar 23 14:07:26 myserver postfix/pickup[12851]: D2B4A4763D: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 23 14:07:26 myserver postfix/cleanup[19630]: D2B4A4763D: message-id=<20150323190726.D2B4A4763D@myserver.example.com>
Mar 23 14:07:26 myserver postfix/qmgr[29583]: D2B4A4763D: from=<root@myserver.example.com>, size=323, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 23 14:07:26 myserver postfix/local[19632]: D2B4A4763D: to=<george@myserver.example.com>, orig_to=<george>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 23 14:07:26 myserver postfix/qmgr[29583]: D2B4A4763D: removed
```

Comment: What's the output of `postconf myhostname`, `postconf myorigin` and `postconf masquerade_domains`?

Comment: Also can you post the maillog when email *sendmail* send email to existed user (for example (george*) so we can understand your case better?

Comment: @masegaloeh: I've edited the OP to add those details.

Answer (score 2):

From the logs, the *domain masquerading* process rewrite both sender and recipient from `something` to `something@myserver.example.com`. The culprit behind this rewriting is paramater `myorigin` and `append_at_myorigin`. As postfix docs said

> **append_at_myorigin (default: yes)**
>
> > With locally submitted mail, append the string "@$myorigin" to mail addresses without domain information. With remotely submitted mail, append the string "@$remote_header_rewrite_domain" instead.
> >
> > Note 1: this feature is enabled by default and must not be turned off. Postfix does not support domain-less addresses.
> >
> > Note 2: with Postfix version 2.2, message header address rewriting happens only when one of the following conditions is true:
> >
> > - The message is received with the Postfix sendmail(1) command,
> > - The message is received from a network client that matches $local_header_rewrite_clients,
> > - The message is received from the network, and the remote_header_rewrite_domain parameter specifies a non-empty value.
> >
> > To get the behavior before Postfix version 2.2, specify "local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all".

In your configuration, postfix append `$myorigin` = `$myhostname` = myserver.example.com to `george`.

Because $myhostname (myserver.example.com) listed in `mydestination, then postfix will try to do user existence checking by

1. Check if the user (george) listed as local user on myserver.example.com
2. Check if the user (george) defined in `alias_maps`

If user doesn't match both checking, the email will bounced. Otherwise email will be delivered to local mailbox.

#### Proposed solution

From the question, looks like you want to rewrite george -> george@example.com instead george -> george@myserver.example.com. Then you can change parameter `myorigin` become `$mydomain`. In `main.cf`

```
myorigin = $mydomain
```